# Pros and cons while migration infosphere 8.7 FixPack1 to 11.3 version?

Tags: datastage

I am working on data stage application usinf InfoSphere 8.7 FixPack tool. Now I am planning to migrate to InfoSphere 11.3 version.
Could you please suggest me the pros and cons which I need to know before migration?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score -1):

I am new on this, and I am migrating from 8.5 To 11.3. Something I learned is not to bother migrating your .ds files, because they won't work with the newer version. Also be sure to install a g++ compiler in your new server.